# Increasing size of SQL Server MDF file

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a 400GB MDF file and its growing by 5GB daily. At the moment, autogrow is set low at 10Mb.

If I grow the file by 10GB, I am guessing this will stall SQL Server and cause lots of timeouts.

Whats the recommended approach here>

Autogrow or take the hit and grow the file nightly?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to NEVER grow it outside maintenance periods. As any sensibly large and busy sql database lives on dedicated storage ANYWAY - you can pre-allocate all the available space during a maintenance window.

Answer (score 0):

MDF file growth is instantaneous with [instant file initialization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935(v=sql.105).aspx).  SQL Server will not stall if you grow the file by 10 TB, let alone 10 GB.  I would recommend you grow the database to the size you expect it to be in the next 12 months in a single operation.  There's no reason to wait for it to expand your file size repeatedly throughout the day or even each night.